# To fall on one's ass

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is the phrase "to fall on one's ass" literal in meaning? Is it only used when someone falls and lands on their ass or can it be used about any fall?

Answer (score 3):

To fall on one's ass (or arse in British English zones) literally is always to fall so that the buttocks contact the ground or floor first, so that person who fell is left in a sitting position, from which it is difficult to recover in a dignified fashion. The expression can also be used figuratively to mean 'suffer an embarrassing accident or failure'. This might be when the unlucky person has been vain or boastful, or has ambitious rivals.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used literally.

It can also be used mockingly of someone who falls over backwards, not necessarily on their ass.

It can also be used metaphorically to mean "to look ridiculous", especially when describing (with glee!) someone proud or ambitious who has failed or suffered a setback. "Pride comes before a fall" is what my grandparents might have said.

Comment: If someone fell on their side or flat on their face, I wouldn't say they fell on their arse (or 'ass').

Comment: Wouldn't you? Mockingly? I suppose "He fell flat on his face" is itself mocking: people rarely fall so precisely. I'll add a "backwards".

Comment: Well, literally means something like 'exactly as stated, not figuratively' so I'd reserve it for when people actually fell on their actual arses. Call me pedantic if you want.